# alert and redirect in codeigniter php using javascript not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, redirect

i have a function my controller, when the user clicks a button, the function runs and should show the alret box and then redirect the user to the same page, so i did the following code:

```html
public function addtowishlist()
{
if($this->session->userdata('id'))
{
$id =$this->uri->segment(3);
$this->product->addtowishlist($id);               
  echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("' . $pname . '")</script>';
redirect($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
}

              }
```

however the issue is the alert is coming fine but the redirect to same page is not happening, only i get a blank page, can anyone please help me with this, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your redirect will execute before alert since `PHP` is serverside and `Javascript` is client side, so what you need is redirect with javascript like this

```
public function addtowishlist() {
 if($this->session->userdata('id')) {
   $id =$this->uri->segment(3);
   $this->product->addtowishlist($id);               
   echo '<script type="text/javascript">
         alert("' . $pname . '");
         window.location.href = "'.$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'].'"; ; 
         </script>';
  }
}
```